# We know that $A^{23} = 0$. What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. We know that $A^{23} = 0$. What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

I think it's just $0$, but I'm not sure. How should I do this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a corresponding eigenvector. Then
$$Ax = \lambda x \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lambda^{23}x = A^{23}x = 0x = 0.$$
Since $x \neq 0$, $\lambda^{23} = 0$ and thus $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: When you don't know how to prove something, it's usually worth a shot to, among the first things, refer to the definition and try if you can get something out of that.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did! I was just entirely unsure of it, thank you!

Comment: For my own curiosity, how are you sure $x$ doesn't equal 0?

Comment: @Stephan An eigenvector is nonzero by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say that $n\ge 23$ so that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix. What about the eigenvalues of a nilpotent matrix?

Answer (score 0):

the polynomial vanishing on A has only one root , which is $0$ which is also the eigenvalue of $A$
there is also a well known result saying that if A is nipotent ovec an algebric closed field its only eigenvalue is $0$

Comment: No need for an algebraically closed field. A nilpotent matrix (of nonzero size) has $0$ as its unique eigenvalue, period.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If you're working over a domain ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pedantically speaking, $0$ is an eigenvalue only if $n>0$ (since the $0\times 0$ matrix has no eigenvalues at all). But there are definitely no other eigenvalues than $0$, since if $P$ is any annihilating polynomial (here $P=X^{23}$), any eigenvalues must be a root of$~P$ (since $P[A]$ acts on an eigenspace for$~\lambda$ by the scalar $P[\lambda]$).